# Reproduce clip-path: polygon with an svg for Microsoft Edge

Tags: svg, polygon, microsoft-edge, clip

[On top is wanted result, below is svg result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMcuf.jpg)

Because Microsoft Edge is not capable of recognizing the property `clip-path: polygon`, I have read somewhere that I should use an SVG image to do the trick.

Here is my original code:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

Here is my attempt to make it work with Edge:

```
clip-path: url('#myclippath');
```

And the svg next to the div:

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <clipPath id="myclippath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0.75, 1.0, 0, 1.0"/>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

The problem is that the SVG shape is applied to the background-image, but not the div itself. Which makes it pretty useless.

Can an SVG shape be applied to a div ? If not, is there a jQuery alternative ( thought I would prefer to stick with CSS)?

Comment: Not in Edge. You'd have to write the whole thing in SVG because in Edge only clip-paths only work on SVG elements.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by the Robert Longson for writing the whole thing in SVG may work. IE and Edge does not supports the clip path but new MS Edge (chromium) will support it.